# A database table having 3 keys

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I have a many to many relationship between `student` and `classes`.

I created another table (junction table) called `student_classes` to hold the primary key of `student` and priamry key of `class`, this enables a many to many relationship to be modelled as standard database design.

I also have another table called `books`, this has core books for a specific classes.

A student can choose which *one* of the core books he/she wants to use for a class. I was going to add it to the `classes` table but the choice of book depends on the student.

Then I thought it would be ideal if Ii could map it onto the junction table - it seemed logical, as a core book depends not only on the student but on the class.

Would this be good design to have the junction table hold another key to the book?

So tables :

```
[student]
stduent_id

[classes]
classes_id

[book]
book_id

[student_classes]
student_id
classes_id
book_id
```

Comment: Is a class the same thing as a course?  Or can there be multiple classes for the same course in the same semester?  Is the book list determined by the class or by the course?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this model (as per your description) student can use only one book for a given subject, if you need more than one, then move `BookID` into the primary key of the `StudentBook` table. Note that there are two foreign keys in `StudentBook` table: `FK1 {StudentID, SubjectID}` and `FK2 {SubjectID, BookID}`.

[image]

Comment: Almost all of my college classes had more than one book!

Answer (score 1):

For the situation you describe, the model you propose will work because, loosely speaking:

- A primary key uniquely defines a row (entity) in the table
- All other columns in the table are attribtes of the primary key
- Here, the primary key is stduent_id + classes_id
- Properly speaking, book_id is an *attribute* of stduent_id + classes_id

To be clear: do not make book_Id part of the primary key, and you're fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
[student_classes] student_id classes_id 
[student_classes_books] student_id classes_id book_id
```

This will allow the student to select more than one book in cases where that is needed. Many classes require more than one core text, in my experience.